# fast quad tree construction, matrix partitioning in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix which I want to divide it into smaller part step by step. In step one, It is itself, a `1 by 1` matrix, In step two it is divided into four submatrices, `2 by 2` matrices, in next step it is divided into sixteen submatrices, `4 by 4` matrices and so on.

My matrices are n by n and power of 2.

How can I do it according to the step I am in and in a fast way?

this is the code I have written but not efficient enough.

```
function [A,B] = qtree(X,K,N,l)

L = log2(N);
wx = (size(X,1))/(2^l); 
wk = (size(K,1))/(2^(L-l)); 
for n=1:2^l
    m (n,:) = (n-1)*wx+1:n*wx ; 
end
for n=1:2^(L-l)
    mm (n,:) = (n-1)*wk+1:n*wk ; 
end
% the ordering is like MATLAB, from top to bottom and left to right
k=1;
for i = 1:size(m,1)
    for j= 1:size(m,1)
        A(:,:,k) = X(m(j,:),m(i,:));
        k = k+1;
    end
end
kk=1;
for i = 1:size(mm,1)
    for j= 1:size(mm,1)
        B(:,:,kk) = K(mm(j,:),mm(i,:));
        kk = kk+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please describe your algorithm and define what you mean by level?

Comment: Don't remove your code though! Also is your matrix guaranteed to be *n*-by-*n* where *n* is a power of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is use to [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to help you decompose the matrix into submatrices where each submatrix belongs to one cell.  After this, simply concatenate all of them into a 3D numerical matrix where the i<sup>th</sup> slice denotes the i<sup>th</sup> submatrix.  As such, starting from the master scale (the original matrix), you would have simply subdivide your rows and columns by powers of 2, put these into cells, then spatially concatenate all of these cells into a numeric 3D matrix.  However, this code assumes that your matrix dimensions are in powers of 2.  Should they not be, then this method won't work.  One suggestion I have is to pad your matrix so that it does fit evenly into a power of two.  What you can do is use [`nextpow2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nextpow2.html) to determine the most compatible power of 2 for your rows and columns, then create a matrix of this increased size and place your matrix inside.  However, if your matrix size is already in a power of 2, then `nextpow2` will simply return the exact `log2` of that number, so there won't be any padding of zeroes when we are finished.  It will simply be the original matrix instead.

I'm not sure what kind of inputs you're using, but this will handle all general size matrices should the sizes not be a power of 2.

---

In other words, given your matrix stored in `A`, and specifying `num_scales` as the amount of times you want to perform these subdivisions, try something like this:

```
[rows, cols] = size(A); %// Get dimensions

%// Determine compatible dimensions for matrix
rows_pad = 2^(nextpow2(rows));
cols_pad = 2^(nextpow2(cols));

%// Create padded matrix
Apad = zeros(rows_pad, cols_pad);
Apad(1:rows, 1:cols) = A;

num_scales = 5; %//Determines number of subdivisions
%// You can also intelligently figure this out by:
%// num_scales = min(log2(rows_pad), log2(cols_pad)) + 1;

for s = 1 : num_scales
    Bcell = mat2cell(A, (rows_pad/(2^(s-1)))*ones(2^(s-1),1), (cols_pad/(2^(s-1)))*ones(2^(s-1),1)).';
    B = cat(3,Bcell{:});

    %// B contains this 3D matrix
    %// Continue your processing...
    %//
end
```

Note that you can intelligently determine how many maximum scales you want to decompose the image by taking the `log2` of the rows and columns and determining the smallest value and adding 1.  I've added this in as a comment after setting `num_scales`.  However, I set this as a constant in case you don't want to decompose the matrix all the way down to single `1 x 1` elements.

`B` contains the 3D matrix where each slice is the i<sup>th</sup> submatrix.  Take note that this code will store the blocks **in row major order**.  This means that the submatrices are taken from left to right, top to bottom.  If you want **column major order**, simply remove the transpose operator (`.'`) at the end of the `Bcell = ...` statement.

Now, that `Bcell = ...` statement is probably throwing you off.  Let's step through this statement slowly.  Here it is again for self-containment:

```
Bcell = mat2cell(A, (rows_pad/(2^(s-1)))*ones(2^(s-1),1), (cols_pad/(2^(s-1)))*ones(2^(s-1),1)).';
```

How `mat2cell` works is that you provide the matrix that you want to partition into cells, which is `Apad` in our case.  The next two inputs are 1D vectors which tell you the dimensions of each block you are partitioning.  The second input works on the rows, while the third input works on the columns.  Therefore, at the first iteration, we just one a single 2D matrix of the same size, and so at scale `1` in the `for` loop, we would simply get a cell matrix of that same size.

At the next iteration, our scale is `2`, so the equivalent call would be:

```
Bcell = mat2cell(Apad, [rows_pad/2 rows_pad/2], [cols_pad/2 cols_pad/2]);
```

This statement essentially creates 4 submatrices where the subdivision happens right in the middle of the rows, and the middle of the columns.  At the third iteration, our scale is `4`, so the equivalent call would be:

```
Bcell = mat2cell(Apad, [rows_pad/4 rows_pad/4 rows_pad/4 rows_pad/4], ...
                [cols_pad/4 cols_pad/4 cols_pad/4 cols_pad/4]);
```

Therefore, we are partitioning the rows and columns equally into 4 segments, which provides as 16 submatrices within a 4 x 4 grid.  That's the purpose of the [`ones`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) statement so that we can replicate this as many times as we need to given the scale.

Finally, we just stack all of these 2D matrices into a 3D matrix using [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and we specify the third dimension as to where we are stacking these matrices.  `B` should contain your final 3D matrix, and you can do whatever processing you want from that point on.

---

This should hopefully be enough to get you started.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried `A = rand(1024,1024)` and `num_scales = 16`. It gives an error

Comment: @shalooshaloo That's because `log2(1024) = 10`.  You are specifying more scales than it can process.  Use `num_scales = 10` instead.

Comment: @shalooshaloo - I've also edited my post to calculate num_scales dynamically in a comment if desired.

Comment: @shalooshaloo - I've encountered some errors as well.  Let me check.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: for my matrix, according to the level I have to divide it into different parts, for example this 1024 by 1024 into 256 matrices, 16 by 16

Comment: @shalooshaloo - Yes.  I know why.  I've made a slight error.  Let me fix.

Comment: @shalooshaloo - fixed.  If you want to have 16 x 16 matrices, you'll need to set `num_scales = 7`, or just bypass the loop and set `s = 7` only.  Also, You will get **4096** total matrices, not 256 as `(4096 * (16 * 16)) = (1024^2)`. This will get you what you need.  Check my edited post.  I did the `Bcell` line wrong!